# Xamarin.Auth Google Logout

Tags: forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, google-authentication

I have a Xamarin Forms project that uses Google Authentication as described [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/). I can log in fine, but I can't figure out a way to truly log out of Google. The Google accounts are stored in the browser, so when I use the Presenter to display the Choose an Account list from Google, the passwords don't need to be entered. Is there a way to force the user to enter their google password every time?

Answer (score 0):

If your open to switching to a different solution to OAuth.   I have used the [Simple Auth Package](https://github.com/Clancey/SimpleAuth).   It provides a method to log out.  The documentation provides a fairly easy implementation.     Once you have the log in set.Use `ResetData();` to log out.

I know this does not answer your question exactly but it would be a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I'll do some testing on this and see if I can swap it in.